# Change Image from Form Input with Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to make a Skin Viewing Website for the game Minecraft and I need to have a simple form that displays an image from Minotar.net and then displays the entered username with thier image / skin under the form

The form should add the username to the end of the url, for example:

Form text submitted: Notch

Changes: img src="https://minotar.net/skin/username" to img src="https://minotar.net/skin/Notch"
and displays the image below the form.

--

The code that I tried

```
      <div class="page-header">
        <h2>Enter a Minecraft Username to download skin:</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="page" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <input type="submit" value="Download Skin!" onclick="goToPage();" class="btn btn-success">
              <img id="page" src="http://minecraft-skin-viewer.com/skin.php?user=">
        </span>
```

Javascript:

`function goToPage() {
                var page = document.getElementById('page').value;
                img.src = "http://minecraft-skin-viewer.com/skin.php?user=" + page    }`

JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4dqbP/14/
Thanks!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  People won't be inclined to help those who haven't made some effort on their own.

Comment: I have searched and tried for a few hours now, and it all failed. sorry but I'm new to javascript and just can't figure it out

Comment: 2 elements with the same id tell me you are new to html too =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, you're doing well for just starting JavaScript.  I found a few errors in your code and corrected them in a JSFiddle at the end of my answer.  Here are your mistakes, for future reference:

1. Unlike classes, ids MUST be unique.  You had two ids both named "page."  This is not valid HTML, and will cause errors.
2. You used `img.src`.  This is allowed, but only if `img` is a variable.  In the fiddle, I made `img` a variable, by using the `getElementById` method.
3. You should close your `img` tags and `input` tags.  People will say "what do you mean, close those tags?"  Well, just for consistency, and making XHTML easier to learn later, it's a good habit to make sure your `input` tag looks like this:

`<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>`

Not this:

`<input type="text" id="textbox2">`
*(Notice the missing "/" at the end.)*

Other than that, I just cleaned up some formatting.  You're good to go!

### [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4dqbP/21/)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm still having one big problem, I can't make the image to change or add the username to the end of the url, would it be possible to share your version of the jsfiddle? Would be a great help! Thank you!

Comment: I was just adding it.  Sorry it tookk me a few minutes.  The internet is slow . . .

Comment: Yes, I think that there is something wrong with my code. Basicly it should add the username that has been entered in the form to the end of the url so that the picture according to that username can be displayed next to it

Comment: Sorry about that.  I put it back in.  Good luck!

Comment: Maybe your URL  is wrong.  Can you give me a valid minecraft username?

Comment: Yes the url is empty atm, a valid username would be ex. "Notch" or "ZanderPlays"

A url with username would be: http://minecraft-skin-viewer.com/skin.php?user=Notch

Comment: + id's cant be the same as per HTML standard, not javascript.
+ older browsers will understand unclosed tags just fine, after all, that's how HTML STILL works, it's xhtml that is restrictive. Yet, yes it's a good practice all around